# Joint Distance to Floor Changes as I move

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect-sdk

I have sucessfully implemented the floor clip plane to measure the distance of left foot to the floor, which is fairly accurate. The problem I have is that as I move away from the camera (i.e. left foot Z angle is increase), the foot distance to the floor changes (increases).

Note: The floor itself is not tilted nor the Kinect stand.

here is the code:

```
if (skeletonframe != null && skeleton.Joints != null)
        {
            float A = skeletonframe.FloorClipPlane.Item1;
            float B = skeletonframe.FloorClipPlane.Item2;
            float C = skeletonframe.FloorClipPlane.Item3;
            float D = skeletonframe.FloorClipPlane.Item4;

            //Calculate the distance from the floor
            //joint head
            float point1 = A * (skeleton.Joints[JointType.FootLeft].Position.X);
            float point2 = B * (skeleton.Joints[JointType.FootLeft].Position.Y);
            float point3 = C * (skeleton.Joints[JointType.FootLeft].Position.Z);

            float point1_d = A * A;
            float point2_d = B * B;
            float point3_d = C * C;


            float numeratore = point1 + point2 + point3 + D;
            float denominatore = point1_d + point2_d + point3_d;

             distance = (numeratore / (float)System.Math.Sqrt(denominatore)) * 10;
```